# How do I add a checkbox to my existing (working) simple AutoHotKey GUI window script?

Tags: user-interface, windows-10, autohotkey

I currently have this:

```
InputBox, UserInput, My private search engine, Specify a search string:, , 320, 128
if not ErrorLevel
{
    UserInput := StrReplace(UserInput, """", "\""")
    Run %ComSpec% /c "php "C:\test\engine.php" "--query=%UserInput%"
}
```

When run, it shows a little GUI window with a simple text input, asking me to enter a query. When I click "OK" or press Enter, it executes my `engine.php` PHP CLI script with the search query as an argument (which does all the actual work). This simple thing took me an **extremely** long time of reading and searching and testing and swearing before I figured out. In particular, the `UserInput := StrReplace(UserInput, """", "\""")` part drove me nearly insane before I figured it out. (If you don't do that, all kinds of input characters break the entire thing.)

It works. However, I have found that I often want to specify some checkbox option, such as `[ ] Skip the videos dir`. So I need to add such a checkbox.

If this had been HTML, I would know how to do it. But it's not. It's AutoHotKey script, and frankly, it's infuriating. I simply cannot figure out how to do it, in spite of reading about the relevant sections in the manual. I've given up at this point, forced to ask for help.

How would I add a checkbox to my existing code, visually underneath my text input box, which is then also sent as an argument such as `... "--option1=%Something%"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to want to create a [gui](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm) for this.
And also I think you're missing, or have one extra, quote in that commandline.
The very first quote (the first one here: `"php "C:\tes...`) doesn't seem to have a closing quote(?)

But anyway, here:

```
#Persistent

Gui, New, -MinimizeBox, % "My private search engine"
Gui, Add, Text, , % "Specify a search string:"
Gui, Add, Edit, vUserInput w300
Gui, Add, Checkbox, vMyCheckbox, % "Check Me!"
Gui, Add, Button, gOkButtonPress w50 h25 x80, % "OK"
Gui, Add, Button, gGuiClose w50 h25 x160 y71, % "Cancel"
Gui, Show, Center
return

OkButtonPress:
    Gui, Submit
    if (MyCheckbox)
        MsgBox, % "Checkbox was checked!"
    else
        MsgBox, % "Checkbox wasn't checked!"
    
    UserInput := StrReplace(UserInput, """", "\""")
    Run, % A_ComSpec " /c ""php ""C:\test\engine.php"" ""--query=" UserInput """"
return

GuiClose:
    ExitApp
return
```

`#Persistent` <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Persistent.htm)</sup> is used so that the script doesn't exit immediately when you run it because there are no hotkeys or anything else that would make the script not exit once code execution is done.

Then it's time to create the gui.
There's quite a bit there to understand if it's your first time working with AHK guis.
Try to keep the relevant documentation pages open and see what I'm doing there.
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#New
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Add
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Events
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#GuiClose
If you don't understand some part of it, just ask.

First I add the text control, edit control, and checkbox control without specifying any x or y coordinates.
This way AHK will just take care of the placement for you and put them nicely underneath each other.
For the two buttons I specified coordinates myself. It's a bit tricky if you're just blindly doing it, but trial and error will get you there, lol.
If you ever want to create more fancy guis, and not pull your hair out while trying to visualize in your head what coordinates and width/height you want, I recommend using e.g. [SmartGuiXp](https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/96299-smartguixp-mod-v43297-by-drugwash/) <sup>[(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOz9q.png)</sup>.
It'll make creating AHK guis a lot more pleasant.

Then I show the gui centered on screen and I let AHK worry about what width/height it should have, so I don't specify any of that.

Also, explicitly specifying string with `% " "` is just personal preference and not needed. It just looks right to me, and doesn't have to legacy AHK feel.

In the `OkButtonPress` label (btw, labels are legacy AHK. I would use functions, but then we would have to worry about variable scopes, so I decided not to make this answer more confusing) the first line is
`Gui, Submit` <sup>[(docs)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Gui.htm#Submit)</sup>
This makes the gui save the contents of our controls to the associated variables.
So our text input to `UserInput` and the state of the checkbox to `MyCheckbox`.

Then we finally get to the run command.
I didn't fix the possible problem with the missing end quote.
I just changed it from legacy syntax to modern expression syntax. Of course you don't need to do that and you can keep it in legacy syntax if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I sure wish all answers on this site were this useful! I got it working. And yes, you are right about me having missed a quote in the end. It's actually there in the real script, but I made a mistake when "preparing" the script to make it suitable to be published in public. I get what you mean by "legacy" AHK code, but for that particular part, I'll stick to the old syntax, if only for the amount of trouble I had to get it working initially! Thanks a lot.